# python importing code from a string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using google app engine and I am trying to basically allow users to upload code, where it will later be executed by the server. I also have to be able to send variables to the scripts, which is why initially when I was running everything on my desktop, I Imported everything dynamically (as in- the name of the script is stored in a variable). But now I can not do this because of the filesystem in the google app engine environment.

I already have a database setup so that I can get the code in plain-text. But now I would like to know if there was any way that I could import a python script, not from a file but from a variable containing python code.

For example, If this was the plain-text code, how could I get this to execute properly:

```
code = """
def Main(var):
    print "you entered: " + var
"""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a module for the code to live in:

```
# define module_name somewhere
import types
module = types.ModuleType(module_name)
```

You'll probably want to register that module, too:

```
import sys
sys.modules[module_name] = module
```

Then compile the code:

```
# source should the code to execute
# filename should be a pseudo-filename that the code's from
# (it doesn't actually have to exist; it's used for error messages)
code_object = compile(source, filename, 'exec')
```

Then execute the code object in the context of the module:

```
exec code_object in module.__dict__
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! How would I send variable information to this code?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that. How could I execute a specific function with variables

Comment: @user1270285: `module` acts just like a real module at that point. Just call it as you would normally call a function in a module: `module.some_function(var1, var2)`

Comment: does registering the module permenantly keep that module available for use even after the first runtime?

Comment: @user1270285: Yes, within that Python interpreter.

Comment: I'm sure you realise how dangerous this is - you're users can potentially do anything you can do, if your app simply excutes their code. You'll have to REALLY trust your users. Imagine someone deleting your data or burning through you resources so you get a humungous bill.

Comment: Yes, I know. For now this is locked down so that Just I can use it. I am trying to think of a way to implement a solution that is safer.  How does a site like wordpress, or any other site allow people to upload code safley?

Comment: @user1270285: Hosted WordPress (wordpress.com) or self-installed WordPress (wordpress.org)? On self-installed WordPress instances, it's the responsibility of the user to ensure that they only upload safe code. As for the hosted WordPress, I'm not entirely sure what they do, but I would guess that they manually screen themes and plugins before allowing it onto their platform.

Comment: Now that I think about it, wordpress may have not been the best example. But Codepad.org is a great example of someone who figured out how to safley allow people to execute code on a website

Comment: @user1270285: codepad [takes *extreme* caution](http://codepad.org/about) in their code execution. You can try to do something like what they do, but not on App Engine, and it would require a *lot* of work.

Comment: Hmm... ok, maybe that will be for another time. This implimentaion of the code above will be very useful to me and trusted others when trying to populate my app with "plugins" (I haven't thought of a cool word yet). But What I may do if other people want to add plugins, they will have to have data sent to another server (like their own) and would send back HTML or something else related. Anything there that I would have to watch out for?

Comment: @user1270285: Perhaps App Engine limits on HTTP requests sent, but besides that, I can't think of anything beyond just the normal things (e.g. escaping where necessary).